Axiom of choice on well order
Given ZF +

If a set A has well order, then there exist function f s.t. for each non-empty set B ∈ A, f(B)∈B.

It's something like Axiom of countable choice, but there can be more than Aleph0 elements as long as such an order exist.
How strong is this? Can it compare with Axiom of dependent choice?

You don't need choice at all for this, since every non-empty subset of a well-ordered set has a minimum. Choice is equivalent to every set being well-ordered.

Prove your property directly in ZF.

@NaïmFavier It's a set of set, nothing about subset, and no promise its union has well order

What is the context for this question? As stated it’s likely to be closed.

@l4m2 Then I don't understand what you mean. Please phrase your statement using precise mathematical notation.

Duplicate confirmed
